# syntax error: unterminated quoted string when using regexp_replace in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, postgresql, database

I've added some code to the end of a bash script I am using. The code shown here is intended to copy a csv into my postgres table, and then remove brackets, quotes and double quotes from the title column of test_table.

```
 #copy csv to table

psql -U postgres -d ebay_sold -c "COPY test_table (item_number,title,url,price) FROM '/home/perl_experiments/xmlcsv.txt' (DELIMITER('|'))"

#Remove brackets, then double qotes, then single quotes from title column
    psql -U postgres -d ebay_sold -c "UPDATE test_table SET title = regexp_replace(title, '[()]', '', 'g')"
    psql -U postgres -d ebay_sold -c "UPDATE test_table SET title = regexp_replace(title, '"', '', 'g')"
    psql -U postgres -d ebay_sold -c "UPDATE test_table SET title = regexp_replace(title, '''', '', 'g')"
```

The copying to the postgres table works fine. The remove brackets, double quotes and single quotes work as expected when applied manually in postgres. However, when I run the bash script, I get:

```
line 27: syntax error: unterminated quoted string
```

The error which i'm getting relates to the line

```
           psql -U postgres -d ebay_sold -c "UPDATE test_table SET title = regexp_replace(title, '"', '', 'g')"
```

As I say this command works fine when performed manually when i'm logged into postgres, does anyone have any idea why i'm getting this error when I run the script in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line:

```
psql -U postgres -d ebay_sold -c "UPDATE test_table SET title = regexp_replace(title, '"', '', 'g')"
```

is the problem.  You open a double-quoted string at `"UPDATE`, but it is closed earlier than you think it is, causing you to attempt to run the following as SQL:

```
UPDATE test_table SET title = regexp_replace(title, '
```

This is clearly not valid.  You need to escape your double-quote with a backslash:

```
psql -U postgres -d ebay_sold -c "UPDATE test_table SET title = regexp_replace(title, '\"', '', 'g')"
```

Comment: HI, sorry, when I copied my script for some reason the end of that line didn't copy onto this webpage, i've updated my question so now it reflects my script, there is a double quote at the end of that line.

Comment: Yes, but that's no help.  `bash` sees `"UPDATE test_table SET title = regexp_replace(title, '"` as a string, the `', '', 'g')` after it as confusing noise, and the `"` at the end of the line as the beginning of a second quoted string (on that line).  No, wait; that's wrong.  It sees `', '` as a second string, `', '` as a third, and then the `'` after the `g` starts a fourth string.

Comment: Not true.  Test with `var="UPDATE test_table SET title = regexp_replace(title, '\"', '', 'g')"; echo $var`  That is exactly what the OP's question was regarding, and what my answer resolves: escaping the double-quote so that `bash` doesn't parse it, allowing it to make it through to `psql`.

Comment: ah, sorry i'll try your edited suggestion now and get back to you